# script is moving past statements and erroring out

Tags: java, user-input

I have a script that is supposed to be a main menu for a luxury cruise travel agency. the main menu displays a range of options to choose from and the user is allowed to pick between them.

```
        Luxury Ocean Cruise Outings
        System Menu

[1] Add Ship            [A] Print Ship Names
[2] Edit Ship           [B] Print Ship In Service List
[3] Add Cruise          [C] Print Ship Full List
[4] Edit Cruise         [D] Print Cruise List
[5] Add Passenger       [E] Print Cruise Details
[6] Edit Passenger      [F] Print Passenger List
[x] Exit System

Enter a menu selection:
```

as such, however if the user selects 1 or 3 the functions to those initiate. the problem is with both sets of methods, once they are done and the program breaks from the addShip(); or the addCruise(); it errors out, as if the code is trying to make a choice on its own instead of waiting for user input, it actually acts like it goes back into the method itself.

this is the result after it completes one of the methods and then goes back to main.

```
    Luxury Ocean Cruise Outings
        System Menu

[1] Add Ship            [A] Print Ship Names
[2] Edit Ship           [B] Print Ship In Service List
[3] Add Cruise          [C] Print Ship Full List
[4] Edit Cruise         [D] Print Cruise List
[5] Add Passenger       [E] Print Cruise Details
[6] Edit Passenger      [F] Print Passenger List
[x] Exit System

Enter a menu selection: Exception in thread "main" 
Ship name: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at luxuryV2/luxuryV2.Driver.addShip(Driver.java:233)
    at luxuryV2/luxuryV2.Driver.mainMenu(Driver.java:46)
    at luxuryV2/luxuryV2.Driver.main(Driver.java:23)
```

and for debugging here is the mainMenu();

```
    public static void mainMenu() {
        char choice = '0';
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
                displayMenu();
                try {
                    //scnr.next();
                    choice = scnr.next().charAt(0); // might throw an exception
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    System.out.println("\n\nException caught - " + e);
                }
                while (choice != 'x') {             
                    if (choice == 'x') {
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (choice == '1') {
                        addShip();
                        displayMenu();
                    }
                    else if (choice == '2') {
                        editShip();
                        displayMenu();
                    }   
                    else if (choice == '3') {
                        addCruise();
                        displayMenu();
                    }
                    else if (choice == '4') {
                        editCruise();
                        displayMenu();
                    }
                    else if (choice == '5') {
                        addPassenger();
                        displayMenu();
                    }
                    else if (choice == '6') {
                        editPassenger();
                        displayMenu();
                    }
                    else if (choice == 'A' || choice == 'a') {
                        printCruiseList("name");
                        displayMenu();
                    }
                    else if (choice == 'B'|| choice == 'b') {
                        printCruiseList("active");
                        displayMenu();
                    }
                    else if (choice == 'C' || choice == 'c') {
                        printCruiseList("full");
                        displayMenu();
                    }
                    else if (choice == 'D' || choice == 'd') {
                        printShipList("list");
                        displayMenu();
                    }
                    else if (choice == 'E' || choice == 'e') {
                        printShipList("details");
                        displayMenu();
                    }
                    else if (choice == 'F' || choice == 'f') {
                        printPassengerList();
                        displayMenu();
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("\nSomething went wrong");
                        System.out.print("\nChoice: ");
                    }
                }
            //close scanner
            scnr.close();
```

and here is the method for the addShip(); (*Note, its extremely similar to the addCruise(); method and for readability I wont include it here.)

```
    public static void addShip() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("\naddShip method not complete.");
        // complete this method
        //shipName; roomBalcony; roomOceanView; roomSuite; roomInterior; inService;
        Ship vessel = new Ship();
        System.out.print("\nShip name: ");
        vessel.setShipName(sc.nextLine());
        //set ship space (Balcony)
        System.out.print("How many balcony rooms: ");
        vessel.setRoomBalcony(sc.nextInt());
        //set ship ocean view rooms (int)
        System.out.print("How many Ocean Veiw rooms: ");
        vessel.setRoomOceanView(sc.nextInt());
        //set suite rooms (int)
        System.out.print("How many Suit rooms: ");
        vessel.setRoomSuite(sc.nextInt());
        //set interior rooms
        System.out.print("How many interior rooms: ");
        vessel.setRoomInterior(sc.nextInt());
        //set active service
        System.out.print("Is the Ship in active service?\n"
                + "1. Yes"
                + "\n2. No"
                + "\nChoice: ");
        int choice;
        choice = sc.nextInt();
        if (choice == 1) {
            vessel.setInService(true);
        }
        else if (choice == 2) {
            vessel.setInService(false);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You entered an incorrect value, setting " + vessel.getShipName() + "to Inactive.");
            vessel.setInService(false);
        }
        //add vessel to list of ships
        shipList.add(vessel);
        //close scanner.
        //sc.next();
        sc.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was closing the scanner object itself, I dont understand the underlying reason but the code did go back after the close of the scanner object and try to read a line. but once I commented out the close(); statement on the scanner object the code was no longer throwing the exception.

Comment: Even though your IDE probably warns you that `Scanner` is never closed, it is an error to close a `Scanner` that reads standard input (i.e. the keyboard).

Comment: Makes sense. But I read somewhere it's better to close scanner statements to keep it from interfering in other parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see,  the `choice` is read from the input just once, before the `while` loop, and it stays the same in each loop iteration. You should add `choice = scnr.next().charAt(0);` at the end of the loop, I guess (I am referring to the `mainMenu` function).

Another problem is that a new Scanner instance is created in each sub-menu.

The way it could be fixed:

- add `choice = scnr.next().charAt(0)` at the and of the loop (with try-catch)
- pass `scnr` as a parameter to the `addShip` function (removing local Scanner from the function and NOT closing scnr in the function)

Comment: the scanner in the main is actually closed when the loop terminates. should I place that inside the loop?

Comment: also, I moved the ```choice``` to inside the loop as well, and im getting the same error, the compiler is going back for the sc.nextLine() argument inside the addShip() method and erroring out there.